# Unable to understand the strange "where" syntax in Haskell / Clash

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, clash

I am quite new to Haskell, and I am currently doing a Clash project. I have struggled for few days to understand what these code means in Haskell:

One example is from the retro-clash book
https://github.com/gergoerdi/retroclash-book-code/blob/master/src/serial/echo/src/Serial.hs

```
topEntity
    :: "CLK" ::: Clock System
    -> "RX"  ::: Signal System Bit
    -> "TX"  ::: Signal System Bit
topEntity = withResetEnableGen board
  where
    board rx = tx
      where
        input = serialRx @8 (SNat @9600) rx
        buf = fifo input txReady
        (tx, txReady) = serialTx @8 (SNat @9600) buf

makeTopEntity 'topEntity
```

The first thing seems confusing to me is, why we can have `board rx = tx`?
like if there is `board = some-expression` it is more understandable to me, because the identification 'board' has just been mentioned in the previous context. But how is `rx` also appear in the left of the equal sign? Is it related to pattern matching? (if is, how can `rx` be matched? like in the definition of `topEnity` there is no `rx` mentioned?)

Also, I can not understand these three line of the inner 'where', the relation between different function names seems really complicated.

Comment: `board rx` defines a function named `board` that takes a single arguent named `rx`.

Comment: I recommend that you read a Haskell tutorial to learn the fundamentals of the syntax. [Learn you a haskell](https://learnyouahaskell.com/introduction) is good and there are many others out there online.

Comment: In a sense, the `where` clause's definition of `board` is the "previous context" for `withResetEnableGen board` rather than the opposite - it's just defined further down. Mathematics uses this kind of notation frequently (although usually just for one "level").

Comment: `board` seems unnecessary; it could be replaced with an inline definition like `\_ -> tx` or `const tx` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to consider a simpler example.  Assuming you've done enough Haskell programming to run into the `map` function, you probably understand the following program to double the elements of a list:

```
doubleList :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleList xs = map double xs

double :: Int -> Int
double x = 2*x
```

You may also know that `doubleList` can be defined without explicitly referencing the argument list `xs`, and it will still behave the same as the original:

```
doubleList :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleList = map double
```

If `double` is only referenced by `doubleList`, it's possible to move its definition into a `where` clause:

```
doubleList :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleList = map double
  where
    double x = 2*x
```

On the other hand, if we thought that the definition of `double` was too complicated, we might rewrite it in terms of some subexpressions defined in its own `where` clause:

```
double x = two * input_number
  where two = 2
        input_number = x
```

or even:

```
double x = output_number
  where two = 2
        input_number = x
        output_number = two * input_number
```

Combining these changes would give:

```
doubleList :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleList = map double
  where 
    double x = output_number
       where 
         input_number = x
         two = 2
         output_number = two * input_number
```

which is similar, in structure, to the Clash example:

```
topEntity :: ...
topEntity = withResetEnableGen board
  where
    board rx = tx
       where
         input = serialRx @8 (SNat @9600) rx
         buf = fifo input txReady
         (tx, txReady) = serialTx @8 (SNat @9600) buf
```

So, in the Clash example, `topEntity` is defined by applying `withResetEnableGen` to a one-argument function `board`:

```
board rx = ...
```

which is, itself, defined in terms of some subexpressions given in a `where` clause.

The only additional wrinkle is that the subexpressions include some mutual recursion, so the result of `board rx` is defined as `tx`, which is part of the output of `serialTx` applied to `buf`, but `buf` is defined in terms of *both* `input` (which depends on the actual argument `rx` passed to `board`) *and* `txReady`, which is another part of the output of `serialTx`.

So, `buf` is calculated based on `txReady`, and `txReady` is calculated based on `buf`.

This is not something you typically see in conventional languages, where this kind of mutual dependence would most likely result in an infinite loop, but it's pretty common in Haskell.

For a non-Clash example, consider this function, which determines which elements of a list are even:

```
isEvenList :: [Int] -> [Bool]
isEvenList = map isEven
  where
    isEven x = check_x
      where
        check_x = e x
        e = check o (True, False)
        o = check e (False, True)
```

using the following helper function:

```
check :: (Int -> a) -> (a, a) -> Int -> a
check f (ifZero, ifOne) y = case y of
  0 -> ifZero
  1 -> ifOne
  _ -> f (y-1)
```

Note that `e` depends on `o` and `o` depends on `e`, just like `buf` and `txReady` in the Clash example, but the program still works fine:

```
> isEvenList [1..10]
[False,True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False,True]
```

That's because `e` and `o` are functions, and `check` ensures that they're called in a way that doesn't result in an infinite loop (i.e., because `e` only calls `o` under certain conditions and vice versa).

Something similar is going on with the Clash example.

Answer (score 4):

```hs
board rx = tx
```

This defines a function named `board` with a single parameter named `rx`. The result of calling this function is the value of `tx` which is defined in the `where` clause.